# HP ProLiant Server HDDs - Buy Spare Parts vs. Retail

Tags: hard-drive, hp, hp-proliant

sometimes i have to upgrade HP Servers. For example when they get a new "job" to do.

So lets say i need some more HDDs for an DL360 G7 Server. If the Server has an active HP Care Pack, does it matter if i buy HP Spare Parts? Often they are much cheaper than retail HDDs. (I often saw on internet e.g. $250 retail / $210 spare part - but it is the same Disk Type!) And if i use them in an Server with active Care Pack, i do not have to worry about the warranty. If the HDD crashes the HDD will be replaced no matter if it was an "retail" Product or an "spare part".

So am i right, or are there any disadvantages i didn't think about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HP ProLiant server warranties follow the chassis. That covers everything inside the machine ***as long as you use HP parts***!!

So the wise thing to do with something like a G7 server in 2014 is:

- Keep the server's warranty active.
- Once you hit the 3 year factory warranty, you can buy additional 1 or 2-year Care Packs if you wish to keep things under support.
- Weigh the cost of those warranty uplifts with the "street value" of used servers. For instance, a DL380 G6 is worth about $400US; less than the $1200US cost of extending the warranty for one.
- You can use any HP parts inside the machine you wish. So please try to find deals on disks... You can even use 8 year-old disks in a warrantied machine and get support replacements. It's the server chassis that counts.
- The parts you receive from HP for warranty replacements are usually refurbished parts.

Answer (score 0):

You are mistaken - per HP's quickspecs on hard drives:

SAS Enterprise hard drives have a 3 year limited warranty regardless of the warranty period for the system in which they are installed.

SAS Midline hard drives have a 1 year limited warranty regardless of the warranty period for the system in which they are installed.

SATA hard drives have a 1 year limited warranty regardless of the warranty period for the system in which they are installed.

Spares have a 30 or 90 day warranty - if the spare warranty is expired, HP does not have to replace the drive. Any other component, besides HDD / SSD, would be covered either retail or spare.

Comment: i think you didn't see, that in my constelation i have an HP Server with activ CARE PACK. So generally you may be right, but with active Care Pack they have to replace the Disk...